# Print the number of movies that was watched by more than 3 people

Tags: python

I want to create a program that can print the number of movies that was watched by more than 3 people (data stored in a nested list as below ).

```
list_movies = [('Spiderman 3', ['John', 'jake','Ronald']),('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald']),
               ('Terminator',['Anne','Johnny','Peter','Ronald','Neville'])]



count2 = 0
for (movie,name) in list_movies:
    count = 0
    for (name) in list_movies:
        if name != '':
            count += 1
    if count > 3:
        count2 += 1

print(count)
print(count2)
```

Comment: What happens if you use `list_movies = [('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald']), ('Terminator',['Anne','Johnny','Peter','Ronald','Neville'])]`? Can you understand why?

Comment: Would you care to explain

Comment: Why are you using a tuple over a dict?

Comment: Well, removing the spiderman movie will print `2` and `0` instead of the (I guess) expected `5` and `2`. This means the code is not working as intended.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger To the best of the authors knowledge. I'm not sure if it falls in that category, else I'll make my answer a community answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make it a function

   This should really be a function for test ability, reuse ability

   It would need to be a function which accepts 2 parameters (The list we want to query, the amount of people have had to watch it)

   And it will return the amount of times this happened

   - Add doc strings to said function, so after a while when you come back to this code, you still understand what you have written

   For example:

   ```
   def list_movies(movie_list, n):
       """
       a method what returns the count of movies watched by more then n people

       args:
           movie_list (list): The list of movies in [(movie, [names]), ..]
           n (int): The amount of times the movies has need to be watched

       returns:
          The count of movies that has been watched by more then n people
       """
   ```
2. Make proper tests

   if you had properly tested this code, @Mathias's comment would probably not be necessary

   There are a few good modules to test functionality [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) or [unittests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

   Let's use doctest and add some tests to the docstring:

   ```
   >>> count_movies_watched([('Spiderman 3', ['John', 'jake','Ronald']),('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald'])], 3)
   1

   >>> count_movies_watched([('Spiderman 3', ['John', 'jake','Ronald']),('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald'])], 4)
   0
   ```

Without even writing a single line of code, it's already more clear, what this function will do and what a correct answer will be.

## Improving Code

- You can use `list comprehension` and the built in `sum` to get a count of movies
- Use `_` for variables you don;t use later on

Netting me:

```
sum([1 if len(names) > n else 0 for _, names in movie_list])
```

But this can also be improved, as @Mathias correctly states

- `sum` will accept any iterable there is no need for the list comprehension
- `sum` can add `bools` as well so no need for the awkward ternary

Netting me:

```
sum(len(names) > n for _, names in movie_list)
```

## Putting it all together

```
import doctest

def count_movies_watched(movie_list, n):
    """
    a method what returns the count of movies watched by more then n people

    args:
        movie_list (list): The list of movies in [(movie, [names]), ..]
        n (int): The amount of times the movies has need to be watched

    returns:
        The count of movies that has been watched by more then n people

    >>> count_movies_watched([('Spiderman 3', ['John', 'jake','Ronald']),('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald'])], 3)
    1

    >>> count_movies_watched([('Spiderman 3', ['John', 'jake','Ronald']),('Gravity',['james','jake','john','gerald'])], 4)
    0
    """
    return sum(len(names) > n for _, names in movie_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: It would be great if i get a detailed code. This seems quite complicated as a I'm a beginner.

Comment: @NisanAbeywickrama As your questions is off topic, I'm afraid I won't be able to add much more to this answer. What is complicated for you, I might shed some light on it